# Find the rank of matrix $B$

Tags: linear-algebra

If $A_{n \times n}$ is a non-singular matrix, such that $A \times B$ is the zero matrix ($n\times n$), then the rank of $B$ is?

(A) $n-1$

(B) $n-2$

(C) $1$

(D) $0$

The answer to this question was given to be (D).

But I am confused why only (D).

$|AB|=0$

$|A|.|B|=0, \;|A| \neq 0 \rightarrow |B| = 0$.

Surely rank of $B$ is less than $n.$ But why exactly $0$?

Comment: Your argument only works if $B$ is square, otherwise it doesn't make sense to talk about its determinant.

Comment: Yes, please guide now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $A$ is non-singular, $A^{-1}$ exists. Then, $B = A^{-1}AB = A^{-1}0 = 0$.

Since $B$ is the zero-matrix (of whatever size), $\text{rank}(B) = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Multiplication $B$ with a non-singular matrix doesn't change its rank.

This can be seen from  a nonsingular matrix can be decomposed into a product of elementary matrices, and we know that performing elementary operation doesn't change the rank of a matrix.

Hence if $A$ is nonsingular and $AB=C$, we have $rank(B)=rank(C)$.